# Showing Items Next to Each other

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to display items in my test project using JSON and RecyclerView. Code works fine but the problem in my code is I am seeing image row by row instead of next to each other. I tried Table Layout and card layout too but it didnt work for me. Any input is highly appreciated.

**Current Dispaly**

```
Image1
Image2
Image3
Image4
Image5
```

**Expected Output**

```
Image1 Image2 Image3
Image4 Image5
```

**Complete Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/PersonImage"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.328"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PersonName"
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PersonImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your root linear `layout_width` to `wrap_content`. Then when you set up recycler change layoutmanager to GridLayoutManager, example:

```
int columnSize = 3;
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, columnSize);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

[Doc link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#GridLayoutManager(android.content.Context,%20int))